# size of QR Code generated from mailmergebarcode in ms word

Tags: ms-word, qr-code, mailmerge

I am trying to generate  QR code using mail merge option in MS Word for below JSON data.
    {'first_name':'Don','last_name':'James','email':'Don.James@mycomp.com','phone_number':'8923212','company_name':'Mycomp Inc','address':'Texas, San Antonio, USA','state':'Texas','country':'USA'}

the command for it is {MERGEBARCODE mydata QR}

I want to reduce width and height of the generate QR code. I am not finding how to do it. any help is much appreciated.

Comment: did you try googling "mergebarcode field" ?

Answer (score 2):

you cannot set height and width of barcode but you can scale the barcode. for scaling a barcode you need to pass second field argument as \s value.value is the scaling factor you want,.

ex: `{MERGEBARCODE myQRMSG QR \s 80}`

it scales your generated barcode from QRMSG column in my excel data source to 80% of its width and height and all the data will be still preserved.

Comment: this should be the answer